# After putting 1 batch CUDA error: device-side assert triggered keeps popping up

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I have a simple Conv model for EMNIST-letters:

```
class CNN(torch.nn.Module):
    @property
    def device(self):
        for p in self.parameters():
            return p.device
        
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        
        self.layers = torch.nn.Sequential()
        self.layers.add_module('conv1', torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 1*6, kernel_size = 5))
        self.layers.add_module('relu1', torch.nn.ReLU())
        self.layers.add_module('pool1', torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 2))
        self.layers.add_module('conv2', torch.nn.Conv2d(1*6, 1*16, kernel_size = 5))
        self.layers.add_module('relu2', torch.nn.ReLU())
        self.layers.add_module('pool2', torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 2))
        self.layers.add_module('flatten', torch.nn.Flatten())
        self.layers.add_module('linear1', torch.nn.Linear(16*4*4, 120))
        self.layers.add_module('relu3', torch.nn.ReLU())
        self.layers.add_module('linear2', torch.nn.Linear(120, 84))
        self.layers.add_module('relu4', torch.nn.ReLU())
        self.layers.add_module('linear3', torch.nn.Linear(84, 26))

    def forward(self, input):
        return self.layers(input)
```

And I have a dataloader:

```
batch_generator = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset = EMNIST_test, 
                                              batch_size=50)
```

After I put 1 batch from batch_generator, I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
```

And it appears if I try to do anything with device. Even if I put my model to device once again I get this error. After such a mistake device is just unavailable. Colab shows there is a lot of free GPU. Did anyone have such a problem?

Comment: Please show the entire error message and flow of code leading to the error (see [mcve]).

Comment: Check for max value in your label and check for number of classes. Means max(label)-1==num_of_classes